# Want to upload and parse a json text and load it to my index page by a click of a button using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I created a text called Name under my content folder. I wrote it in Json format.  I am trying to take that Name.text and display it after the result of clicking a button. I came up with some parsing code to parse the json. I just dont know where to put it at. I think it go in my success: function(data) area somewhere. Please help me out.

```
<p>
  <script type ="text/jscript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $.ajax({
              url: "/MvcApplication1/Content/Name.txt",
              success: function (data) {
                  var jsnObj=$parseJSON(data);
                  $("#button").click(function(){
                       $("p").append(jsonObj.First);
                       $("P".append(jsonObj.Last);

                   });

              },
              error: function () {
                  alert("error");
              }
          });
      });

  </script>
</p>
<div id="nameDiv"></div>
<button id ="button><Get Name</button>
```

Comment: (object.test) = (object.text)?

Comment: what? Can you elaborate  more please?

Comment: im not sure.. i've seen some other examples and was trying to incorporate it into my code. I just want to parse my Name.txt file and display it on my index page. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, create 2 functions, one that does the Ajax and one that does the parsing, you need to pass the "data" to the parse function .

```
  function doParse(jsondata) {

     var jsonobj = $.parseJSON(jsondata);

     /*  ... next stuff */

    /* UPDATE ( as comment ): say jsonobj  is {"pizzatype":"ham"} */
    /* output examples */
     alert(jsonobj.pizzatype);
     $("#mydivonthepage").html("My favourite pizza is"+jsonobj.pizzatype);


    }

     $(document).ready(function () {
      $.ajax({
          url: "/MvcApplication1/Content/Name.txt",
          success: function (data) {
              doParse(data);
          },
          error: function () {
              alert("error");
          }
      });
  });
```

NB* you can simplfy further - see getJSON for examples -http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: how can i display the data to the index page after clicking the button

Comment: hi, updated answer with basic example, see NB* link at bottom for more dynamic uses.

Comment: Okay I got it working now...the problem was that i forgot the "$" in front..but how do you make separate lines for example.. I$("#nameDiv").html(jsnObj.First + jsnObj.Last);  how do i get First name on line number one.then a line break then Last name?

Comment: I got it now no go on different lines.
I did the following:

        <p id="p1"></p>
        <p id="p2"></p>

then
   
         $("#p1").append(jsnObj.First);
         $("#p2").append(jsnObj.Last);

Comment: I got it now no go on different lines.
I did the following:

        <p id="p1"></p>
        <p id="p2"></p>

then
   
         $("#p1").append(jsnObj.First);
         $("#p2").append(jsnObj.Last);

Comment: that will work - or $("#nameDiv").html(jsnObj.First +"<br/>"+ jsnObj.Last); - glad you got there, is this answer accepted ?